# sql retrieve data between timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to extract all fields from my database that are between the ultima_modifica field (TIMESTAMP) and ultima_modifica + attesa(Enum '1','3','5')

[image]
last_change is a timestamp

ultima_modifica is a (ENUM)

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE ultima_modifica between ultima_modifica and ultima_modifica + interval attesa minute
```

In this way I retrieve all the results

The goal is to retrieve only the data that are between my timestamp (ultima_modifica) and my timestamp ultima_modifica + Enum (3)

Thanks for help

Comment: All *what* "fields"?  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: You can export DDL of the table in text format and paste it into the question. Text is more accessible and readable to all. Also, it is described in question guide: [**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `TIMESTAMPADD`:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE ultima_modifica BETWEEN ultima_modifica AND TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE, attesa, ultima_modifica);
```

By using `TIMESTAMPADD` we get around the problem of working with the literal value needed for `INTERVAL`.  This answer assumes that `attesa` is a column in your table whose units are minutes.

Comment: I change my post original post

Comment: My basic answer does not change, only the column names have changed.

Answer (score 0):

This is your filtering condition:

```
WHERE last_change between last_change and last_change  + interval wait_time minute
```

Well, there are three possibilities:

- If `last_change` or `wait_time` are `NULL`, then no rows are returned.
- If `wait_time` is negative, then no rows are returned.
- Otherwise, *all* rows are returned.

Why?  Because any given time is always going to be "between" that time and a time a few minutes in the future.

So, your intentions are entirely unclear.   Your query is generally going to return all rows.  And always going to return all rows with non-`NULL` and non-negative values.

Comment: I change my post original post

Comment: I solved in this way..

SELECT * FROM cars WHERE NOW() between ultima_modifica and ultima_modifica + interval '300' minute

sorry guys but it was my error

thanks all